# How to add lines to a file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to add parsed information to a text file using Nokogiri. I would like to append every new string to the existing file.

```
divs_with_links = uni_page.css('div.border-top_lightgrey')
divs_with_links.each_with_index do |div, index|
  if div.css('h3').text == 'Biology'
    uni_link = div.css("span.external-url").text || "no link found"
    uni_email = div.css("p.email").text || "no email found"
    data = "#{current_uni_title}|#{uni_link}|#{uni_email}"
    open("uni.csv", "w"){ |file| file.write(data)}
    break
  end
end
```

Every time I parse a new page, Nokogiri deletes the file contents.

Comment: When programming, and especially when asking programming questions, it's really important to understand what components in your code do what. Nokogiri has nothing to do with files, it only parses text, returning information about what it found. Then you have to use IO or File to read/write/update/delete the files. That's immediately your clue where you should look, as `open` belongs to those classes, not Nokogiri. Searching the documentation will tell you that. And the documentation would have led to [the solution](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong [mode opening a file](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-new):

```
- open("uni.csv", "w"){ |file| file.write(data)}
#                  ⇓ appends, not overrides content
+ open("uni.csv", "a"){ |file| file.write(data)}
```